# Need help getting my Android TableLayout to work properly

Tags: android

I am attempting to display data from the on-board SQLite database within a table in the Android UI, but it isn't working as it should. Here is what I have:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/data_table"
    android:stretchColumns="3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:layout_column="1" android:text="id" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" />
        <TextView android:layout_column="2" android:text="firstname" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" />
        <TextView android:layout_column="3" android:text="lastname" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
List<People> listOfPeople = databaseHelper.getAllPeople();

TableLayout myTableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.data_table);

for(People person : listOfPeople){
    TableRow newTableRow = new TableRow(this);
    TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
    newTableRow.setLayoutParams(rowParams);

    TextView idTV = new TextView(this);
    idTV.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(1));
    idTV.setText(person.getId());

    TextView firstnameTV = new TextView(this);
    firstnameTV.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(2));
    firstnameTV.setText(person.getFirstname());

    TextView lastnameTV = new TextView(this);
    lastnameTV.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(3));
    lastnameTV.setText(person.getLastname());

    newTableRow.addView(idTV);
    newTableRow.addView(firstnameTV);
    newTableRow.addView(lastnameTV);

    myTableLayout.addView(newTableRow);
}
```

The table and data is displayed, but the data within the rows I built from the database are all smooshed together and unreadable. If I were to compare this to web development, it looks like all the data are in one cell of the table row.

I am very new at Android development (former JSP developer), and what I have here, I have tried to piece together from Google searches. I need to use a TableLayout so a grid layout (or any other layout) will not do.

**EDIT:**

I added some background color to my "cells" and discovered they are in different cells. The issue, apparently, is that they are not distributing themselves correctly as I am not sure how to add "layout_width" and "layout_weight" to the cells within Java. At least, I guess that is what the issue is.

Comment: Please post an image of what you want it to look like.  You probably want to use a [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) here.

Comment: I want it to look like a data table (Excel, HTML, etc.). Columns with headers, then rows underneath with the corresponding data.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your xml to this:

```
<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/data_table" android:stretchColumns="1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TableRow>
    <TextView android:layout_column="1" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="id" />
    <TextView android:layout_column="2" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="firstname" />
    <TextView android:layout_column="3" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="lastname" />
</TableRow>
```

Make sure to also set the layout_weight to 1, for all the TextViews added by java code.

Comment: Although I didn't put it here, I do have layout_weight and layout_width set in my XML file. I added a background color to the table "cells" and now see that they are not all smooshed together, rather they are just not distributing themselves properly. I will edit my original post with this information as well.

Comment: You missed the android:stretchColumns="1" attribute in TableLayout tag.

Comment: Sorry ... actually I did, but forgot to add that to my SO question; it is there now. My column headers distribute perfectly evenly, but not the rest of the table body. When I set the width using "idTV.setWidth(0);" it looks like it wants to distribute evenly, but I need the "weight" attribute set, but cannot figure out how to do that in Java.